# Fastest Way to read CSV to list of tuples with condition/filter and column type assignment? (Python)

Tags: python, read.csv, memory-efficient, timeit

Hi Everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

I need to read a csv to a list of tuples while conditioning the list on a value (>=0.75) and changing the columns to different typing.
***Please Note you can not!! use pandas, NO PANDAS***

I'm trying to figure out how to do it the FASTEST method possible.

This is how I did it (put i think it is not efficient):

```
def load_csv_to_list(path):
  with open(path) as csv_file:
    table = list(reader(csv_file))
  lst = [table[0]]
  count = 0
  for row in table[1:]:
    if float(row[2]) >= 0.75:
      date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
      row = (date,int(row[1]),float(row[2]))
      lst.append(row)
  return (lst)

start = timeit.timeit()
load_csv_to_list(path)
end = timeit.timeit()
print(start - end)
```

answer : 0.00013872199997422285